pytorch Keypoint RCNN model - android error torchvision::nms
I developed a Keypoint RCNN Detection model, but when deploying it on Android, I encountered this error:
Process: com.example.java_pytorch, PID: 5028
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.java_pytorch/com.example.java_pytorch.MainActivity}: com.facebook.jni.CppException:
Unknown builtin op: torchvision::nms.
Could not find any similar ops to torchvision::nms. This op may not exist or may not be currently supported in TorchScript.
:
File "code/torch/torchvision/models/detection/keypoint_rcnn/___torch_mangle_501.py", line 783
_360 = torch.index(boxes4, _359)
_361 = annotate(List[Optional[Tensor]], [curr_indices])
curr_keep_indices = ops.torchvision.nms(_360, torch.index(scores1, _361), 0.69999999999999996)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
_362 = annotate(List[Optional[Tensor]], [curr_keep_indices])
_363 = torch.index(curr_indices, _362)
I've already included these dependencies:
implementation ‘org.pytorch:pytorch_android:1.13.0 implementation ‘org.pytorch:pytorch_android_torchvision:1.13.0 implementation ‘org.pytorch:torchvision_ops:0.13.0 implementation ‘com.facebook.soloader:nativeloader:0.8.0
Can anyone help me understand and resolve this error?
Android source code and i have developed this model from this source https://medium.com/@alexppppp/how-to-train-a-custom-keypoint-detection-model-with-pytorch-d9af90e111da
package com.example.java_pytorch;

// MainActivity.java


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.pytorch.IValue;
//import org.pytorch.LiteModuleLoader;
import org.pytorch.Module;
import org.pytorch.Tensor;
import org.pytorch.torchvision.TensorImageUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.soloader.nativeloader.NativeLoader;
import com.facebook.soloader.nativeloader.SystemDelegate;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {

    private static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
    private boolean mIsCameraPermissionGranted = false;
    private Button mStartCameraButton;
    private ImageView mImageView;

    private Module mPyTorchModel;
    static {
        if (!NativeLoader.isInitialized()) {
            NativeLoader.init(new SystemDelegate());
        }
        NativeLoader.loadLibrary("pytorch_jni");

    }
        static {
            System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3"); // Adjust the name based on your OpenCV version
        }


    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                    break;
                default:
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        mOpenCvCameraView = findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

        mStartCameraButton = findViewById(R.id.start_camera_button);
        mStartCameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startCamera();
            }
        });

        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            mIsCameraPermissionGranted = true;
        }

        // Load PyTorch model
        mPyTorchModel = Module.load(assetFilePath(getApplicationContext(), "mobilenetv2_quantized.pt"));
    }

    private void startCamera() {
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library not found!");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION, this, mLoaderCallback);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
            mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mIsCameraPermissionGranted = true;
                startCamera(); // Start camera after getting permission
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Camera permission is required for this app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mIsCameraPermissionGranted) {
            startCamera(); // Start camera when the activity resumes
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null) {
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null) {
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {}

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {}

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        Mat rgba = inputFrame.rgba();

        // Convert Mat to Bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rgba.cols(), rgba.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(rgba, bitmap);

        // Process bitmap with PyTorch model
        Tensor inputTensor = TensorImageUtils.bitmapToFloat32Tensor(bitmap,
                TensorImageUtils.TORCHVISION_NORM_MEAN_RGB, TensorImageUtils.TORCHVISION_NORM_STD_RGB);

        try {
            IValue output = mPyTorchModel.forward(IValue.from(inputTensor));
            // Process output and draw keypoints on rgba Mat
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error processing image with PyTorch model: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return rgba;
    }

    private String assetFilePath(Context context, String assetName) {
        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), assetName);
        try (InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(assetName)) {
            try (FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
                int read;
                while ((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                os.flush();
            }
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

